# How do I impose initial conditions to solve a nonlinear ode in Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations

I’m trying to solve u_xx + x/2 u_x = 0, with t=0 as x goes to infinity, not sure how to impose initial conditions though? Thankyou

Comment: Please add the code you've tried to your question, and if `u_xx` and `u_x` are variables, don't use underscore; Mathematica doesn't like underscore in symbol names.

Answer (score 1):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

eqn = {u''[x] + x/2 u'[x] == 0, u[0] == u0};

sol = DSolve[eqn, u, x][[1]]

(* {u -> Function[{x}, u0 + Sqrt[π] C[1] Erf[x/2]]} *)

eqn /. sol

(* {True, True} *)

u[Infinity] /. sol

u0 + Sqrt[π] C[1]
```

For `u` to go to 0 at infinity, set the arbitrary constant to `C[1] -> -u0/Sqrt[Pi]`

```
sol2[x_, u0_] = (u /. sol /. C[1] -> -u0/Sqrt[Pi])[x] // FullSimplify

(* u0 Erfc[x/2] *)

sol2[Infinity, u0]

(* 0 *)

sol2[-Infinity, u0]

(* 2 u0 *)

Plot[Evaluate@Table[sol2[x, u0], {u0, 5, 1, -1}],
 {x, -4, 5}, PlotLegends -> Range[5, 1, -1]]
```

[image]